# What's the recommended folder structure of catalogs in project using IoC

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, architecture, inversion-of-control

I've read few articles and watched many lectures/tutorials on YT about DI and IoC, but I didn't find any recommended layout of catalogs in VS solution.

I'm talking about the project (a game for example) where you have few classes/interfaces, logger, database provider, wcf services, wpf presentation layer (that's actually different project)...

Is there any pattern project, that shows how should I organize my project, so next, experienced programmer will not waste time figuring out what's going on? Like we're talking about "self commented code", I'm talking about "self commented project structure".

For example, should I put all interfaces into "Interfaces" catalog? Or should I (in case of logger) create "Logger" catalog and put there interface, classes, class with extension methods (all, focused on logging). Code focused on Board, in "Board" catalog. Separate catalog for "Field" etc etc..

Right now the structure looks like that. I'm not sure about "Business" there and Logger. I have interface in different catalog then other logger classes. Should I call Log4Net provider? or adapter? or decorator? It's just a logger class implementing `ILogger` interface. Here is the screen: [link](https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/09/07/ScreenShot2015-09-08at00.56.03.png)

Here is the sample code (there is no IoC yet, but everybody will notice there will be 3 interfaces there mapped. Very simple):

```
public class Game
{
    public IBoard Board { get; set; }

    public Game(IBoard board)
    {
        Board = board;
    }
}

public interface IBoard {}

public class Board : IBoard
{
    public IField[,] Fields { get; set; }
    public Board(IField field, int boardWidth, int boardHeight)
    {
        Fields = new IField[boardHeight, boardWidth];
        Fields.Initialize();
    }
}

public interface IField {}

public class Field : IField {}

public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(LogEntry entry);
}
```

Comment: Strictly opinion based - use layout that works for you/your team. Often framework that you using would suggest some layout (i.e. ASP.Net MVC suggests controllers/models/views folders), but there is no real golden standard for that (and it will likely vary among different DI containers too).

Comment: Take a look at the [onion](https://rules.ssw.com.au/do-you-know-the-layers-of-the-onion-architecture) architecture

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What I usually do is that I have a `MyApplication.Core` (Class library) layer, which contains all the applications interfaces with as little (read: none) third-party dependencies, e.g. `ILogger`, `ICommand` or `IQuery<TResult>`.

Next I have a `MyApplication.Domain` (Class library)  layer which contains all the application domain specific knowledge - this is the business layer. This is implementations of the core interfaces `ICommand`, `IQuery<TResult>`. These implementations then have an dependency on e.g. `ILogger`. Never concrete implementations.

Then I have the `MyApplication.Infrastructure` (Class library) which is where all the service interfaces from `MyApplication.Core` is implemented, e.g. `ILogger`. Here you can have dependencies on third-party libraries such as Log4Net.

Then last I have the presentation layer, which is in my case usually an MVC applications so I would name this `MyApplication.Web.Mvc`. All controllers have only dependencies on the interfaces. Never concrete implementations. This layer is also responsible of bootstrapping all the interfaces to the concrete implementations using a [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

TL;DR:

- MyApplication.Core (Application Interface Layer)
- MyApplication.Domain (Business Logic)
- MyApplication.Infrastructure (Implementations of Application Interface Layer)
- MyApplication.Web.Mvc (Presentation and Composition Root Layer)

Comment: So, in `Core` I have only interfaces, in `Domain` I have classes with game logic (implementing above interfaces), so Game, Board, Field. `Infrastructure` is kind of still a little bit unclear - is it a places only for third-party libraries "providers"? Where to place code related to database - in `Infrastructure` ?

Comment: `Domain` is the business logic, that is where your entities are . Yes, in my opinion the third party integrations should only be done in `Infrastructure` this is also where your database connections are set up - probably though a simple `IRepository<TEntity>` from `Core` abstraction so your entities can work with the database though an interface instead directly though hard dependency.

Comment: You can check out https://github.com/janhartmann/nerve-framework which is a infrastructure library I've made. An example application can be viewed at https://github.com/janhartmann/nerve-framework-sample - it can give you ideas on how to structure an application.

Comment: One more thing: What do you think about putting all Core/Domain/Infrastructure into single project - let's say "Core". Inside you could split them into different folders (with names as you suggested). So all code will be in single dll. Another projects are gonna be created for presentation - WPF in my case? - this is my first idea. The second idea is the same as first, only 3rd-parties put in different dll (so Infrastructure separated, Core+Domain in single project (split in different folders). What do you think about these two?

Comment: I would not recommend putting everything in a single DLL. This can complicate things when you wish to switch out dependencies (this is what it's all about in the end). I can accept that you have a `Domain` layer where you contain both `Core` and `Domain` in one DLL. But `Infrastructure` should be separate.

Comment: oh, and the LAST question: what non-interface class could be in core? or is it Core=Interfaces only?

Comment: `Core` is not just interfaces. There could extensions methods (e.g. StringExtensions, DateTimeExtensions, Helper method) and application configuration settings which is needed across all layers. :-)

Comment: If the DTOs should be used across all layers, they must be in core. Since the Web/UI layer should only reference infrastructure assembly for composition the DTOs should not live in that assembly. Extensions should placed accordingly, Web/UI extensions should e.g. not be placed in core

Comment: So, where do you put your domain models and entities? In the core? Since interfaces are defined in the core so domain models and entities should also be defined in the core, right? Cause interfaces will be using those domain models and entities as return type.

Answer (score 11):

From [Microsoft's "Common web application architectures"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures).

[image]

[image]

**The Application Core Project**

The Application Core holds the business model, which includes entities, services, and interfaces. These interfaces include abstractions for operations that will be performed using Infrastructure, such as data access, file system access, network calls, etc. Sometimes services or interfaces defined at this layer will need to work with non-entity types that have no dependencies on UI or Infrastructure. These can be defined as simple Data Transfer Objects (DTOs).

**The Infrastructure Project**

The Infrastructure project typically includes data access implementations. In a typical ASP.NET Core web application, these implementations include the Entity Framework (EF) DbContext, any EF Core Migration objects that have been defined, and data access implementation classes. The most common way to abstract data access implementation code is through the use of the Repository design pattern.

In addition to data access implementations, the Infrastructure project should contain implementations of services that must interact with infrastructure concerns. These services should implement interfaces defined in the Application Core, and so Infrastructure should have a reference to the Application Core project.

**The ASP.NET Core Web App Project**

The user interface layer in an ASP.NET Core MVC application is the entry point for the application. This project should reference the Application Core project, and its types should interact with infrastructure strictly through interfaces defined in Application Core. No direct instantiation of or static calls to the Infrastructure layer types should be allowed in the UI layer.

**A starting point repo for Clean Architecture with ASP.NET Core**
https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture